# How to get a channel ID from a channel name for a channel with spaces in between

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

Trying the below HTTP Get Requests

URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
getReqParams = {"key": "YOUR_API_KEY", "forUsername": "Traveling Desi", "part": "id"}

URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
getReqParams = {"key": "YOUR_API_KEY", "forUsername": "AutoVlog", "part": "id"}

It does not return anything in the item list. The channel names were copied directly from YouTube.

Code Sample

```
import requests 
channelName = "Traveling Desi"
   
URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels"
getReqParams = {"key":"YOUR_API_KEY", "forUsername": channelName, "part": "id"}

r = requests.get(url=URL, params=getReqParams)
```

Comment: Can you include [a minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code and be more specific about the problem please?  Does the code return any errors?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have included  a code sample in the question, it does not return any error but does not return a channel ID as well, the items list is empty. If I set the channelName to "Shmee150" or "DailyDrivenExotics", it works as expected. I tried using the YouTube data API direct from their website https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list. Where it does not work as well

Comment: It looks like a YouTube Data API v3 backend bug. You may be interested in reporting your issue through [Google issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/).